# How to display KB, MB, GB, TB in chart.js tooltip

Tags: chart.js

I'm using chart.js 2.80.  I'm retrieving data from MySQL using PHP and graphing it. My data is currently shown in tooltips as bytes. The xAxis shows as KB, MB, GB, etc.  How can I get it to show the same way in the tooltips as bytes is too long to read?

```
    // Set new default font family and font color to mimic Bootstrap's default styling
Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontFamily = 'Nunito', '-apple-system,system-ui,BlinkMacSystemFont,"Segoe UI",Roboto,"Helvetica Neue",Arial,sans-serif';
Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontColor = '#858796';

// horizontalBar Chart
var ctx = document.getElementById("topDestinations");
var myPieChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'horizontalBar',
  data: {
    labels: <?php echo json_encode($destination); ?>,
    datasets: [{
      data: <?php echo json_encode($total_destination); ?>,
      //backgroundColor: ['#4e73df', '#1cc88a', '#36b9cc'],
      backgroundColor: poolColors(10),
      //hoverBackgroundColor: ['#2e59d9', '#17a673', '#2c9faf'],
      hoverBackgroundColor: ['#2e59d9', '#2e59d9','#2e59d9','#2e59d9','#2e59d9','#2e59d9','#2e59d9','#2e59d9','#2e59d9','#2e59d9',],
      hoverBorderColor: "rgba(234, 236, 244, 1)",
    }],
  },
  options: {
    maintainAspectRatio: false,
    
 scales: {
        xAxes: [{
          ticks: {
            beginAtZero: true,
    
        // Convert to KB, MB, GB    
        callback: function(bytes){
            var unit = 1000 ;
            if (bytes < unit) return bytes ;
            var exp = Math.floor(Math.log(bytes) / Math.log(unit));
            var pre = "kMGTPE".charAt(exp-1);
            var result = bytes / Math.pow(unit, exp);
            if(result/100 < 1)
                return (Math.round( result * 10 ) / 10) +pre;
            else
                return Math.round(result) + pre;
        }
                }
            }]
      },
    
    tooltips: {
      backgroundColor: "rgb(255,255,255)",
      bodyFontColor: "#858796",
      borderColor: '#dddfeb',
      borderWidth: 1,
      xPadding: 15,
      yPadding: 15,
      displayColors: false,
      caretPadding: 10,
    },
    legend: {
      display: false
    },
    cutoutPercentage: 80,
  },
});
```

Comment: Tooltips also has callbacks property which is an object that contains several properties like: title, afterTitle, label, etc. In these properties you can define function that has two parameters : tooltipItem, data. You can process the data and then return information exactly what you need.

Comment: Between your xAxis callback and [this doc example](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/2.8.0/configuration/tooltip.html#label-callback) for the tooltip label callback I'm sure you can manage to make it work. The [documentation for all tooltip labels](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/2.8.0/configuration/tooltip.html#tooltip-callbacks) is just before the example. And consider switching soon to the newer versions of the library - there are a lot of improvements in the last 4 years, but the transition is in most cases smooth. Good luck!